# Bluetooth headphone that supports "aptX" Detect

Tags: android, bluetooth

when a Bluetooth headphone that supports aptX is connected via Bluetooth to an android smartphone which also supports aptX (Bluetooth audio codec) then detect in-app code.

Have you any idea how to detect aptX supports headphone or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a few solutions here:

- use Android HCI Snoop on your Android device if available (since 4.x)

  1. Developper options -> enable HCI snoop
  2. Once this setting is activated Android will save the packet capture to /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log (sometimes goes to  /data/log/bt/btsnoop_hci.log instead)
  3. Use adb (Android Debug Bridge) tool to get the file to your local PC using:
     adb pull /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log
  4. Feed Wireshark with this file
  5. Look in Wireshark for Bluetooth Codec negociation phase frames
- sniff bluetooth frames via a Mac OSX host using "Bluetooth Explorer" (Hardware and IO tools for Apple Developers)
- buy a dedicated device to sniff bluetooth frames like "UBERTOOTH ONE" and use btscanner (on Kali linux, for example)